# If $p>3$ and $p+2$ are twin primes then $6\mid p+1$

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, twin-primes

I have to prove that if $p$ and $p+2$ are twin primes, $p>3$, then $6\ |\ (p+1)$. 
I figure that any prime number greater than 3 is odd, and therefore $p+1$ is definitely even, therefore $2\ |\ (p+1)$. And if I can somehow prove $3\ |\ (p+1)$, then I would be done. But I'm not sure how to do that. Help!

Comment: Exploit the fact that we can write any prime $p\gt3$ as $p=6n\pm1$.

Answer (score 8):

**The easy way.**

Note that one of $p,p+1,p+2$ must be divisible by $3$, since they are three consecutive numbers, and since $p$ and $p+2$ are prime, that must be $p+1$. We can do the same to show that $p+1$ is divisible by $2$.

---

**Looking modulo $6$.**

We can look $\mod 6$. We see that
\begin{align}
6k+0\equiv 0\mod 6&\Rightarrow 6|6k+0\\
6k+1\equiv 1\mod 6&\Rightarrow \text{possibly prime}\\
6k+2\equiv 2\mod 6&\Rightarrow 2|6k+2\\
6k+3\equiv 3\mod 6&\Rightarrow 3|6k+3\\
6k+4\equiv 4\mod 6&\Rightarrow 2|6k+4\\
6k+5\equiv 5\mod 6&\Rightarrow \text{possibly prime}\\
\end{align}

So for a number to be prime it must be either of the form $6k+1$ or $6k-1$ (equivalent to $6k+5$ since $6k-1=6(k-1)+5$). So if you have two primes, $p$ and $p+2$, then $p=6k-1$ and $p+2=6k+1$ for some $k$; thus, $p+1=6k$ is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: i like this answer.  It uses $6$ rather than $3$ and ignores that we have $2$ taken care of already by a different argument.  However, I might be misunderstanding something when you write $2|6k + 0$ in the third line.  Don't you mean $2|6k + 2$? Similarly for the next two lines where $3$ and $4$ are the remainders..

Comment: @FrankHubeny, yes, thank you. That was a result of some not-reading-my-copy-paste-work thourough enough.

Answer (score 6):

If $p = 3k+1$ then $p+2$ is not prime.So $p=3k+2$ and you are done.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for every integer $k$, exactly one of $k,k+1$ is divisible by $2$ and exactly one of $k,k+1,k+2$ is divisible by $3$. What do your hypothesis tell you if you put $k=p$?

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider a triple {*m,n,o*} of consecutive natural numbers.
2. Then, at least one of these numbers must be divisible by 2 - an *even* number, and at least one of these numbers - *even* or *odd* - must be divisible by 3 (not necessarily but possibly the same number).
3. The triple must either be *odd-even-odd* or *even-odd-even*.
4. Since all twin primes are odd primes, only an *odd-even-odd* triple can contain a twin prime tuple.
5. So, because of (2.), for primes > 3, the middle number *n* between twin primes must be both divisible by 2 and 3.
6. In other words, in the triple {*p, n, p+2*} (| *p*+2 prime),  *n ≡ 0* (mod 6). ■